# Why does `Rails.application.credentials.api_key` return `nil` in my Rails 5.2 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm trying to add a key for an external api I am using by editing my `config/credentials.yml.enc` file. I run the command `EDITOR="subl --wait" rails credentials:edit` in the command line to open the file which looks like this after adding my API key:

```
secret_key_base: lalala

locationiq_key: blahblahblah
```

In theory I should be able to access the `locationiq_key` variable in the console but when I run `Rails.application.credentials.locationiq_key` it returns `nil`. When I run `Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base` it returns `lalala` as expected. Running `Rails.application.credentials` returns:

```
#<ActiveSupport::EncryptedConfiguration:0x00005b310d378 @key_path=#<Pathname:/home/me/Desktop/coder-app/config/master.key>, @content_path=#<Pathname:/home/me/Desktop/coder-app/config/credentials.yml.enc>, @env_key="RAILS_MASTER_KEY", @raise_if_missing_key=false, @encryptor=#<ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor:0x00007f4c474ed0 @secret="\x7(\x67N!S\xE38\xF\x16^\xDD\x02\xC\x1A\xEN", @sign_secret=nil, @cipher="ays-985-gcm", @aead_mode=true, @verifier=ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::NullVerifier, @serializer=Marshal, @options={:cipher=>"aes-128-gcm"}, @rotations=[]>, @config={:secret_key_base=>"lalala"}, @options={}>
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you reload the console after adding this key into this file ?

Comment: @Pragya Actually, it's working in development but not when i push to Heroku. Am I mising something?

Comment: May be this file hasn't pushed to heroku. Check gitignore file. Otherwise you can also set all environment variables in heroku settings and use it directly in your app.

Comment: Just run the command "heroku run bash" . it will open the heroku bash. Then you can check your file weather this file is updated after pushing the code or not.

Comment: I solved it by adding the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` to Heroku. Working now.